# Variables no reconocidas (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cuando creo nuevas variables y entro en modo de interrupción no puedo ver el valor de las mismas mediante la colocación del cursor encima de ellas o mediante la ventana de inspección. En esta puedo leer el error de que "**El nombre no existe en el contexto actual**". Esto me sucede en todos los Web Forms del proyecto. Sin embargo en otro tipo de proyectos el funcionamiento es correcto. Por ejemplo con Xamarin Android va perfectamente.

Esto me ha sucedido tras unas semanas trabajando con un proyecto de Xamarin Android. Cuando he vuelto a abrir el proyecto de ASP.NET (.NET Framework) con lenguaje de C# veo que no puedo ver los valores de las variables. Se compila correctamente y el funcionamiento de todo el código escrito anteriormente es correcto. No puedo depurar nada nuevo porque este comportamiento no me permite inspeccionar los valores de las variables.

En modo de interrupción, si coloco el cursor sobre el indicador rojo del punto me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Observo que no existe el archivo PDB del proyecto. Creo que el problema puede deberse a que no existe este archivo. Pero compilo de nuevo y no se genera.

Saludos

Comment: VS2010, VS2013, VS2015, VS2017, VS2019, VS2022? Cuál es el build number. Esto ocurrió después de una actualización? Actualizaste Windows? Cambiaste a windows11? Revisaste los foros de VS si a alguien le pasa lo mismo? Es VS para Mac? Qué tal añadir las variables a un Watch? Estás depurando las vistas? Ocurre en todos los proyectos o solo ese?

Comment: Usaste la inspeccion de variables en su ventana?

Comment: Son muchas las preguntas que dejas abiertas, deberías pasarte por [ask] y, si no lo hiciste todavía realizar el [tour]

Comment: Posiblemente tengas el código en modo release.

Comment: Gracias Arriel! Los datos de versión son: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
Versión 16.11.11. De .NET Framework, Version 4.8.03752. No he cambiado a a Windows 11, Uso Windows 10. He mirado las preguntas y respuestas pero no he encontrado solución de momento. Las variables son realmente todas las que yo he declarado en todo las páginas. El comportamiento es todo el proyecto, y en los nuevos que creo. Sin embargo en el de Xamarin Android funciona correctamente.

Comment: Gracias Ramiro. El comportamiento es en todo el proyecto y las ventanas de inspección también. La típica información del valor de la variable al poner el cursor sobre ella es lo que ahora no funciona.

Comment: Gracias Óscar! La pregunta es la que expone el titular. La información que añado es para dar detalles de las circunstancias en las que cambió el comportamiento. Comento lo del IndexOf debido a que ha coincidido su funcionamiento imprevisto con el comportamiento que he descrito. Pero la pregunta es una.

Comment: Gracias PaperBirdMaster! El administrador de configuración de compilación está en Debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución al problema. La causa es la actualización a VS Professional 2019, v. 16.11.11. Las páginas no admitían código nuevo. Creando un proyecto nuevo y nuevas páginas el comportamiento es normal en cuanto a todas las posibilidades de inspección del código en modo de interrupción.
El problema ha sido el trabajo que me ha dado crear todos los formularios y pegar el código en los archivos .CS y .ASPX. Desconozco si habría otra solución menos engorrosa, pero esta ha funcionado y es lo que más me importa ahora mismo.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Parándome a leer esto quería preguntarte una cosa: ¿Estás seguro de que cuando paras la ejecución con el breakpoint, la variable que quieres ver tiene un valor (aunque sea null)?. Digo esto porque parece que cuando intuyes que 'no funciona' es porque a lo mejor la ejecución no ha llegado a ese punto, y por tanto, la variable no está inicializada y, digamos, no existe para ese momento de la ejecución.

En cierto modo es como preguntar por el resultado de una operación que todavía no se ha hecho, por tanto, todavía no existe un resultado

Saludos!

Comment: Pues sí; completamente seguro ya que lo he probado en muchos casos en los que la variable debería tener un valor. Por ejemplo: int i = 2 * 2, y cosas así. De todas formas, el problema está en que las variables no son reconocidas en el contexto. No existen. Lo he comprobado en la ventana de inspección. La razón la desconozco. He pensado que quizás pueda ser que en algunas ocasiones he cargado en el proyecto de Xamarin Android un Web Forms para ver el código. Puede que en ese entorno esos objetos se hayan modificado (aunque creo que no). En fin, continuamos investigando. Gracias!